# To subtract two dates without Using DateAdd Function or DateDiff Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How i got this output, can you please explain the reason behind it?

```
declare @a datetime = '2017-06-08 16:02:22.467',
        @b datetime = '2017-10-23 00:00:00.000'

select DAY(@a - @b) 

select @a - @b
```

Output:

```
17
1899-08-17 16:02:22.467
```

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: The information in this answer is relevant only to the `DateTime` data type. It doesn't apply to the newer data types (`DateTime2` , `Date` and `Time`).

Well, dates in sql server are stored as the number of days since 1900-01-01.
You can see it if you run this query:

```
SELECT CAST(0 as datetime)
```

You'll get `1900-01-01 00:00:00` as the result.

Time is stored as the number of ticks since midnight.
There are 300 ticks per second.

Since the date in `@a` is before the date in `@b`, you get a negative result for the date (-137), and that number is then added to `01-01-1900` to give you `1899-08-17`. The time in `@a` is after the time in `@b`, and since the time in `@b` is midnight, you get the time of `@a` in the result.

Comment: @VenkataramanR Thanks! You might also want to check out [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/) over on my blog for slightly more details and links to even more blog posts on the subject.

Comment: Yes. went through the post and referred links. Very useful. thanks for your time in writing the blogpost. It was enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @a datetime = '2017-06-08 16:02:22.467',
        @b datetime = '2017-10-23 00:00:00.000'

select datediff(day, @a, @b)
```

it returns 137, so difference between these two days are 137.

```
declare @c as datetime = null;
select isnull(@c, 0)
```

it return `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`, it means the default value for the datetime is `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`

In your case this `select @a-@b` minus operation is subtracting the actual difference of 137 days with the default value.

```
select dateadd(day, -137, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

it returns `1899-08-17 00:00:00.000`

if it is `select @b-@a`, it will return `1900-05-17 07:57:37.533` i.e, it will add 137 days from the default value.

and [`DAY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/day-transact-sql) function simply returns the day of the given date.

So for the `1899-08-17` the DAY() should be `17`

Answer (score 0):

Well when you substracting 2 dates zero value for `datetime` type is `1900-01-01 00:00:00.00`.

But from SQL 2008 microsoft created new type `datetime2` and as far as you get overflow (negative value) in here it casts result to `datetime2` that statrs from `0001-01-01 00:00:00.00`

[`DAY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/day-transact-sql) function only get date part from your `datetime` or `datetime2` type.

Answer (score 0):

This will subtract the two date and will add it to Minimum Date in SQL which is '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'. So after subtracting both dates and getting the difference, it will add it in subsequent minimum date which is '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'.